# How to set tag for button in cell iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

I tried to set `tag` for button inside cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     [cell.btnWithIdCell setTag: (int) self.responseObject[@"results"][indexPath.row][@"id"]];
}
```

After in event click by button I try to get `tag`:

```
- (IBAction)open:(id)sender {
    NSString* tagString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [sender tag]];
}
```

It gives me wrong number `tagString`.

How to set tag for button from response object?

Comment: Can you show the whole `cellForRowAtIndexPath`method, and try logging your tag value in this method and in `open`.

Comment: i think you have problem with IBAction Button. now in modern objectiveC you have to Associated method. it is very easy and fast for objC. check my answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set tag of button in cell :

```
cell.btnWithIdCell.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Comment: I need to set tag from my response object only, not index

Answer (score 0):

Just use of your response object(should be in type which can assigned to tag) in place of indexPath and use logic in button action according to app requirement.

Answer (score 0):

What is a "wrong" tag? Because tag is an NSInteger, and I believe your call `(int) self...[indexPath.row][@"id"]` returns a reference object, which is not a NSInteger but perhaps a NSNumber *

So you'd need to add `[... integerValue]` to the end of that call when setting the button's tag

Answer (score -1):

in your IBAction please use `- (IBAction)open:(UIButton *)sender` insted of `- (IBAction)open:(id)sender`
 if there is not work then use another way to get data in IBAction like below method is very easy and very fast insted of `tag`

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

Then use you `tableview` methods and `IBAction` same like Below code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    objc_setAssociatedObject(cell.btnWithIdCell, @"yourObjKey", self.responseObject[@"results"][indexPath.row][@"id"], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);

    [cell.btnWithIdCell addTarget:self action:@selector(open:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (IBAction)open:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSString *tagString = objc_getAssociatedObject(sender, @"yourObjKey");
}
```